# React + Redux почему при обновлении хранилища не обновляется элемент

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы после получения данных с сервера компонент автоматом обновлялся. Нашел информацию про функцию connect(), redux-logger показывает, что редюсер отрабатывает, redux-devtools показывает, что хранилище обновляется, но пропсы компонента не изменяются, соответственно компонент не перерисовывается. Как правильно подписать компонент на изменения хранилища.

Хранилище создаю так:

```
import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from "redux";
import {logger} from "redux-logger";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import promise from "redux-promise-middleware";

import reducers from "./reducers/combineReducer";

const middlewares = applyMiddleware(promise, thunk, logger);

export default createStore(reducers, middlewares);
```

Приложение:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import store from "../store";
//import ...

ReactDOM.render (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Layout} />
        // прочие страницы
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
 </Provider>, document.querySelector ("#root"));
```

Собственно компонент:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Layout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        // разметка
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    data: state.data,
    page: state.page,
    fetching: state.fetching,
    fetched: state.fetched,
    error: state.error,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Layout);
```

Comment: ну так а где функция запроса вызвается?

Comment: Повешена на кнопку. Там экшн срабатывает и логгер фиксирует работу редьюсера, если нужно могу привести код компонента

Comment: да, обнови вопрос и добавь туда код этого компонента

Comment: Добавил разметку компонента, а заодно и экшн с редюсером.

Comment: fetchSmallData и fetchBigData откуда в Layout?

Comment: Импортированы. Строго говоря компонент вообще в отдельном файле, просто мне показалось, что тут будет уместно вставить прямо в разметку. В общем ошибка не в импорте - функция срабатывает и логгер это фиксирует. Как проверить изменяется ли стор? Если не изменяется, как понять почему? Если не изменяется как понять почему элемент не получает новые пропсы? Как вообще ОТЛАЖИВАТЬ реакт?

Comment: redux devtools в помощь

Comment: Спасибо, подключил, посмотрел - хранилище обновляется, но компонент по-прежнему не хочет.

Comment: можешь в какую-то песочницу код добавить?

Comment: не представляю куда можно добавить код на реакте, он же не будет работать.

Comment: codesandbox, например

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Причина была там, где ее не ждали, а именно в

```
import reducers from "./reducers/combineReducer"
```

В хранилище попадала более сложная структура данных, а именно

```
export default combineReducers({
  data: fetchDataReducer
})
```

Исправление требовалось в

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    data: state.data.data,
    page: state.data.page,
    fetching: state.data.fetching,
    fetched: state.data.fetched,
    error: state.data.error,
  };
}
```

Поля, на которые изначально ориентировался компонент всегда оставались `undefined`, поэтому компонент и не обновлялся.